# Keep delimiter as token when tokenizing in OpenSearch

Tags: tokenize, opensearch

How do I define a tokenizer in OpenSearch that keeps the specified delimiters as tokens?

Input: `lorem123+ipsum-dolar` with delimiters `+`, `-`

Output Tokens: `lorem123`, `+`, `ipsum`, `-`, `dolar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally accomplished this by using a regex pattern with lookahead and lookbehind, which is described here for example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-split-string-keep-delimiters#3-positive-lookahead-or-lookbehind

The tokenizer for my question looks as follows:

```json
"tokenizer": {
    "type": "pattern",
    "pattern": "((?<=[+-])|(?=[+-]))"
}
```